# Operation was aborted while establishing a connection

Tags: wpf, wcf

Intermittent WCF Error but unable to reproduce locally

In our application we are getting Operation was aborted while establishing a connection to net.tcp://XXXX. We are using WPF application to connect WCF service.

Tried to reproduce the error by recycle IIS pool, stopped WCF service but did not worked

Operation was aborted while establishing a connection to net.tcp://XXXX.

```
<binding name="MTOMCustomBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
                            receiveTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
                    <mtomMessageEncoding maxBufferSize="2147483647"  >
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="22524288" maxArrayLength="22524288"
                                  maxBytesPerRead="22524288" maxNameTableCharCount="22524288" />
                    </mtomMessageEncoding>

</binding>



<endpoint address="net.tcp://XXXX.svc" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MTOMCustomBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceViewEventBehavior" contract="XXXXXXX">
    <identity>
        <userPrincipalName value="XXXXXX" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>

<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceViewEventBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is intermittent, not accidental. When will such an error happen?
Under a normal circumstance, if the connection works properly, it seems to have something to do with the performance of the machine because of the large file transfer involved.
At last, the custom binding use http base address instead of Nettcp protocol address, so I don’t think the service endpoint address could be connected by using nettcp base address. It should throw an error when hosting the service, like below.

> Unable to find a base address with an endpoint bound to CustomBinding
>   that matches the schema http.  The registered base address scheme is
>   [net.tcp]

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.